# GA4 Explore grand total of isn't matching up with the grand total of data being exported from Explore

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

When I pull my report from the GA4 Explore section, the grand total is different than the grand total of the data I export (see image).

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fw03g.png)

UI Grand Total = 108,395

Grand Total From CSV Export of Explore = 106,362

Question: Are one of these totals sampled? If so which one?

It claims to be 100% unsampled data when looking at the explore (top right green checkmark) inside GA4.